# p-inputMask displaying black border when loading and then removes after in some milliseconds

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, primeng

Using prime-ng version - 5.2.0
browser - chrome

p-inputMask displaying black border when loading for some time and then the border is removed in some milliseconds.
When looking on the Developer tools options it is found that it is due to user agent stylesheet.

Please look at the screen shots below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to hide this black border when the `p-inputMask` is loaded.

I have tried using `p-inputMask:focus { outline: transparent 1px solid }` , but that also wont work and displays the black border at the initial load time.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Use "styleClass" properties provided by PrimeNG to add calss to  and then use :focus pseudo to override the css outline property.